# Running RVIZ with or Without Gazebo Launch for Data Visualization

Tags: gazebo, rviz, ros-melodic, motoman, motoman-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to visualise my robot (Motorman Sia10f) in RVIZ...but when I do so it's showing that there is no tf data and a warning in the Global Status.

Do I need to launch the model in Gazebo first and then run RVIZ?

What is the possible reason for this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328374/for-visualising-data-in-rviz-is-it-necessary-to-launch-the-model-in-gazebo-first-and-then-run-rviz?-or-is-it-possible-to-run-rviz-directly-without-launching-gazebo?/) by [mkb_10062949](https://answers.ros.org/users/44036/mkb_10062949/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2019-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need someone who publisch the TF, because you can ran it with real hardware without Gazebo. but if gazebo is publisching the tf then you need it, but you can start it after you started RViZ

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkb_10062949](https://answers.ros.org/users/44036/mkb_10062949/) on 2019-07-12**:
But the problem is that RVIZ shows no TF data if I launch it first and then launch Gazebo.
any suggestions?

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-07-13**:
Then the tf data is published by the gazebo Sim try the tfthree command.

**Comment by [mkb_10062949](https://answers.ros.org/users/44036/mkb_10062949/) on 2019-07-13**:
sorry which command? can you post it here